# Can a (WMB) message flow have multiple monitoring profiles?

Tags: messagebroker

I need to emit the same events (Start/End/Rollback) from a message flow twice - as they need to be consumed by two different data services who require different data. So I need two monitoring profiles applied to the same flow.

Is this possible?

When actually consuming the data, I plan to use subscription filtering to differentiate the events emitted from the two profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to have 2 monitoring profiles attached.

But you can always reprocess the monitoring event messages in an other flow. So the flow which you are monitoring could emit events with all the data needed in them while a second flow can transform these and create the different messages you need for the different consumers.

Comment: I tried deploying multiple profile as configurable services but seems I can only assign one to a flow at one time. So what you suggest seems to be the only option.